# Grease Pencil - Lines Jitter when Camera Moves

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil, lineart, lines

I'm currently having one small issue with Grease Pencil, and that's with how the lines look when rendered and exported after camera movements are added.

When there's no camera movement, the line quality looks fine and good. But when I add any pans or zooms, the lines have this slight "jittery" quality to them.

I have looked all over FAQ's, forums and YouTube for a solution to this, and even took to Twitter to ask the general public for solutions, but I can't find one anywhere.

If anyone here has a solution, I would deeply appreciate it.